# Use Java drawString to achieve the following Text alignment

Tags: java

I wish to use Java2D drawString to achieve the following looks.

However, I have 0 idea how I an achieve the following text alignment?

As we can see, "Date:", "Open:", ... are all being aligned to left.

And "30-Nov-09", '1262.000", ... are all being aligned to right.

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/drawstring.png](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/drawstring.png)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To right-align text you can figure out the width of the text you're rendering, and then subtract that width from the x-coordinate. eg:

```
g.drawString(s, rightEdge - fontMetrics.stringWidth(s), y);
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to speed it up I elaborated Laurence answer:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)graphics;
g2.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12)); // monospace not necessary
FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
String s = "Whatever";
g2.drawString(s, rightEdge - fontMetrics.stringWidth(s), y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to `drawString`, but in general if you want to print sets of strings formatted into a fixed width you can simply generate the each line as a string by concatenating the fields there with the required number of spaces in between. The code would look something like this:

```
String[] makeLines(String[] labels, String[] data, int width){
   String[] lines=new String[labels.length];
   StringBuilder spaces=new StringBuilder();
   for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
      spaces.append(" ");

   for (int i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
      lines[i]=labels[i]+spaces.substring(0,width-data[i].length()-labels[i].length())+data[i];
   }
   return lines;
}
```

Edit: As Laurence Gonsalves pointed out, this works for fixed size fonts only.